# What is this C++ C11 syntax: "= {}"?

Tags: c++, c++11, uniform-initialization, aggregate-initialization

I came across this syntax in a c++ file:

```
Obj obj = {};
```

What does it do? Does it just call the default constructor?

Comment: Depends. If `Obj` is `int`, then there's no constructor.

Comment: it's really depends on how the assignment operator is implemented.

Comment: @DavidHaim: No, it has absolutely nothing at all to do with any assignment operators.

Comment: I just noticed that this question is about both C++ and C. Those are two very different languages and the answer is very different for each!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Braces around expressions represent aggregation of values, and `{}` represents an empty list of values.

Yes, `{}` simply calls the default constructor. (It also ensures that all members are initialized somehow, even if the class provides no default constructor. This is called "value initialization.")

Before C++11, it would use aggregate initialization with default values for all the members. However, this was already the same as value initialization, i.e. the behavior of "calling the default constructor." (In fact, value initialization is a notion invented by C++03 to allow constructor-oriented syntax to represent something which had already existed with aggregate types.)

There is a little quirk: it will not call a default constructor declared `explicit`, instead producing an error. The solution is never to declare an `explicit` default constructor. If you're stuck with such a constructor, get rid of the `=` and say `Obj obj{}`.

Comment: `Obj obj()` is the most vexing parse, that is, it declares a function called `obj` that takes no argument and returns an `Obj`.

Comment: @KerrekSB Then it's just not default constructible. (I was wrong about unions, the default constructor is implicitly defined as deleted.) Initialization is a whole world of complexity…

Comment: You're right about default constructors. Class types can have implicitly declared ones; the special value initialization rules apply when no default constructor is *user provided*.

Answer (score 4):

This form of initialization is called *list-initialization* in C++11 and *copy-list-initialization* in C++14. It is equivalent to *direct-list-initialization* `Obj obj{};` (in the language of C++14), provided the required constructor is non-`explicit`, which just value-initializes the object.

(What this means in detail depends on whether `Obj` is a fundamental type or a class type, and what kind of constructors have been declared for it.)

Answer (score 1):

For C, this syntax of empty `{}` is not valid. For a valid initializer you need at least one value for a field. The C standards promotes `{ 0 }` as a universal all-to-zero initializer that would be the equivalent to C++'s `{}`.

Comment: Equivalent, but it should be noted that aside from C-like types, that won't in general work in C++.